# Given a list of integers and an integer k, return whether k can be built as a sum of any numbers from that list or their multiplications

Tags: loops, recursion, math, nested-loops

a friend of mine was asked on interview to solve the following exercise but didn't succed. I wanted to try it on my own but it seems to be harded than I though at first glance, so Stack community, please, help :)

> Given a list of integers and an integer k, return whether k can be
> built as a sum of any numbers from that list or a sum of any multiplications of these numbers.
>
> ex: for given [2,3,4] and k = 13 for the following found combinations
> method should return true.
> 1) 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3 
> 2) 2, 2, 2, 3, 4 
> 3) 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 
> 4) 2, 3, 4, 4 
> 5) 3, 3, 3, 4

What I already tried is something like this:

```
List<Integer> inputList = new List<Integer>{
        2, 3, 4
};
Integer k = 13;
Boolean result = false;

for (Integer i = 0; i < inputList.size(); i++) {
    for (Integer j = 0; j < inputList.size(); j++) {
        if (k >= inputList.get(i) && Math.mod(k - inputList.get(i), inputList.get(j)) == 0) {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (result == true) {
        break;
    }
}

return result;
```

but unfortunately, it is not correct solution, because it doesn't consider the case, when k can be indivisible by each of number from input list, but stil more than two numbers (or their multiplicationsthe) summarized together can result a given k. Consider prime numbers like for instance: [17, 53, 97] and k=167. Neither of them is a k divider, but summed up result in 167.

Any ideas how to figure it out? I'm thinking about recursion but I was also told, that this can be solved in an easier way, in just about 10 lines of code.

PS: I've written my snippet in APEX which is a kind of simplified java. It doesn't have streams, vectors,
extensive collections etc but the task is rather a math problem so any kind of help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the multiplication matters since addition can achieve the same result. Try this DP method

```
L=[1]+[0]*k
for n in nums:
    for m in range(n,k+1):
        L[m]+=L[m-n]
print(L[-1]>0) #L[-1] is the number of combinations you can reach k by addition
```